# Consuming FIPS validated OpenSSL runtime

Tags: openssl

I have a series of queries related to FIPS and OpenSSL since I am not aware much about it. Here is the basic question to confirm my understanding.

I have OpenSSL runtime binaries provided by third party as a part of their product. My application is supposed to consume those third party modules, which may internally be using the OpenSSL runtime. In my application, I am not setting the FIPS mode explicitly using `FIPS_mode_set()`. Here are the queries related to the context provided above in the paragraph.

1. If my application is not setting FIPS mode explicitly by `FIPS_mode_set()`, does that mean the non-FIPS mode is set for my application and NO FIPS 140-2 validated cryptography will be used, even if they are available in OpenSSL runtime ?
2. Is there any way to cross check if the third party binaries are setting FIPS mode ?

Answer (score 2):

> I have a series of queries related to FIPS and OpenSSL since I am not aware much about it.

You should familiarize yourself with [User Guide for the OpenSSL FIPS Object Module v2.0](http://openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf).

---

> If my application is not setting FIPS mode explicitly by `FIPS_mode_set()`, does that mean the non-FIPS mode is set for my application and NO FIPS 140-2 validated cryptography will be used, even if they are available in OpenSSL runtime ?

Someone has to call `FIPS_mode_set()` with a non-zero value and the call has to succeed. Typically you call it like so. Its based on the example from the User Guide, page 55:

```
#ifdef OPENSSL_FIPS 
if(FIPS_mode_set(1)) 
{
    fprintf(stdout,"FIPS validated cryptography\n");
} 
else
{
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    exit(1); 
}
#endif
```

A successful call means the library passed the initialization self tests and it disable non-FIPS algorithms.

If (1) no one calls `FIPS_mode_set()` with a non-zero value, or (2) the call fails, then you are *not* using FIPS validated cryptography.

If (1) or (2) occurs, all the cryptography will still be available. It just won't be FIPS validated.

---

> Is there any way to cross check if the third party binaries are setting FIPS mode

Call `FIPS_mode()` or `FIPS_module_mode()`. If it returns 0, then you are *not* operating in FIPS mode. If it returns non-0, then you are in FIPS mode.

Based on the example from the User Guide, page 55:

```
#ifdef OPENSSL_FIPS
if (FIPS_mode())
{
    fprintf(stdout,"FIPS validated cryptography\n");
}
else
#endif
{
    fprintf(stdout,"No FIPS validated cryptography\n");
}
```

---

You may experience some pain points with symbols like `FIPS_mode()`. That's because you did *not* configure and build for FIPS. So preprocessor macros like `OPENSSL_FIPS` won't be defined when you compile and link your program.

In this case, you will probably need to `dlopen` the library provided by the vendor and then locate the symbols with `dlsym`. On Windows, you will call `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`. With a symbol in hand, you can indirectly call `FIPS_mode()`.

Also see the [Dynamically Loaded (DL) Libraries HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/dl-libraries.html) or search Stack Overflow.